# LESS error with webpack build

Tags: css, less, webpack

I'm not sure why I am getting this error. I looked at some LESS documentation and the syntax seems correct. I am using webpack and some loaders:

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './app/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: './public/js',
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    debug: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loaders: ['react-hot','jsx-loader'], include: path.join(__dirname, 'app') },
            { test: /\.es6$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
            { test: /\.less$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style!css!less'},
            { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),
    ]
};
```

When I want to run in watch mode I use this one. The webpack config below is the one generating the error.

```
var Webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var config = require("./webpack.config.js");

var port = process.env.WEBPACK_PORT || 8080;
var host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';

config.entry.unshift(
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://" + host + ":" + port,
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server"   // only prevents reload on syntax errors
);

config.plugins = [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {
                    allChunks: true
        }),
    new Webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
];

config.module.loaders = [
    { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
    { test: /\.es6$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
    { test: /\.less$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style!css!less'},
    { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
];

// dev server for react hot loader
config.devServer = {
    publicPath:  "/js/",
    filename: 'main.js',
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot:         true,
    inline:      true,
    lazy:        false,
    quiet:       true,
    noInfo:      true,
    headers:     {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
    stats:       {colors: true},
    host:        "0.0.0.0",
    port:        port
};

module.exports = config;
```

Error:

```
 /Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:664
[1]       throw err;
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] SyntaxError: /Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/app/styles/index.less: Unexpected token (1:0)
[1] > 1 | @import "generic.less";
[1]     | ^
[1]   2 | @import "buttons.less";
[1]   3 | @import "register.less";
[1]   4 | 
[1]     at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
[1]     at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
[1]     at Parser.pp.parseDecorator (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:170:10)
[1]     at Parser.pp.parseDecorators (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:156:37)
[1]     at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:58:10)
[1]     at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:621:22)
[1]     at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:30:21)
[1]     at Parser.parse (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/index.js:70:17)
[1]     at Object.parse (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:45:50)
[1]     at Object.exports.default (/Users/bli1/Development/Javascript/ReviewWeb/node_modules/babel-core/lib/helpers/parse.js:36:18)
[1] 23 Oct 17:12:37 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: what are you using to compile it ? Also, what happens if you just have that single line in your file ? I have a feeling that the first line is not actually where the problem is.

Comment: @AminMeyghani I'm using webpack and a loaders. `{ test: /\.less$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style!css!less'},`

Comment: what does it say if you just have a basic line of LESS? Do you have the `less-loader` installed ? Also try restarting webpack.

Comment: Also make sure you have `style-loader` and `css-loader` installed.

Comment: @AminMeyghani  I have everything installed and restarted webpack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93221/discussion-between-amin-meyghani-and-liondancer).